# Deploying ASP.NET MVC web project by remotely building committed VisualSVN code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, publishing, web-deployment-project, visualsvn-server

Publishing my entire application to a server in the U.S. every time I change a single line of code is taking FOREVER.

I'm running VisualSVN server on my production server. How can I auto-build my project (to a development site folder) on the server whenever a commit is made? And is this a good practice?

---

**Update:** I'm now looking into the Web Deployment Tool.

Comment: I'm now using Visual Studio's 1-Click publishing to deploy my working copy, which speeds up employment quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're describing the need for a Continuous Integration Server.

Have a look at [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [CruiseControl.Net](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: My projects are mostly one-man shows. Is there a simpler way to deploy without setting up an entire CI service?